# Excel formula to split the text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to split the below text like given below using Excel formula.

[image: Split text]

Comment: Image isn't loading

Comment: With Excel O365, you could add in `B2`: `=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," / ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit : I misread your question and provided different solution earlier.
Here's is the formula

> =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*999+1,999))

Answer (score 0):

Do you need formulas? I think text to column would work much better. Just set / as the delimiter and split column A. After, do a clean-up by looking for and removing spaces.