# How to create a long row of names out of two lists in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to make a long column of names that are made up of two lists, like so:

```
List 1: Library, Theater, Cinema, Casino 

List 2: CityCentre, CentreEdge, OuterCity, Rural
```

Turn it into a column:

```
Library_CityCentre,
Library_CentreEdge,
Library_OuterCity,
Library_Rural,
Theater_CityCentre,
Theater_CentreEdge,
Theater_OuterCity,
etc...
```

Edit:
Here is a sample picture of the excel:
[Excel Sample of the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8sVP.png)

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46685851/1578604) help?

Comment: How is the list presented? Text in a cell? Separate cells? Please show your data sample in an Excel context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to have your output in a single column.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(List_1,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/COUNTA(List_2))+1,1) & "_" & INDEX(List_2,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,COUNTA(List_2))+1,1),"")
```

and fill down as far as needed.

If your lists are set up differently, you can adjust the formula to fit, but the idea is using the `INDEX` function and a mathematical formula to return the appropriate items from each list (array).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was precisely what i was looking for. Now I just need to figure out how your formula works exactly (never used such formulas before)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
=$B$1 & "_" &  A2
=$C$1 & "_" &  A2
=$D$1 & "_" &  A2
=$E$1 & "_" &  A2
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Suggest mixed references:  eg: I'd just use `B2:  =B$1&"_"&$A2` and fill down and right.